# SQL Column Concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to concatenate the column names in my query result if the column is true.  Below is the format of my data, and the format of the intended output as well as a snippet of the SQL I attempted.

DATA

```
ID | ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD
1  | T    | F    | T    | F
2  | F    | T    | F    | T
3  | T    | F    | T    | F
4  | F    | T    | F    | T
5  | T    | F    | T    | F
```

INTENDED OUTPUT

```
ID | TYPE
1  | ColA,ColC
2  | ColB,ColD
3  | ColA,ColC
4  | ColB,ColD
5  | ColA,ColC
```

ATTEMPTED SQL

```
SELECT UniqueIDColumn,
    CASE WHEN ColA = 1 THEN 'A' END + ', ' + 
    CASE WHEN ColB = 1 THEN 'B' END + ', ' +
    CASE WHEN ColC = 1 THEN 'C' END + ', ' +
    CASE WHEN ColD = 1 THEN 'D' END 
FROM TableName
```

Comment: What's the problem with the solution you have?

Comment: Not clear! If you pass 'A', how  is it possible to get A and C for 1? I think you want to pass 'T' instead 'A'!

Comment: @s15199d : I have edited the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a function that receives two parameter, and, if the first parameter is true, returns the second parameter plus a delimiter (e.g., space), otherwise just the delimiter:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS returnNameIfTrue;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION returnNameIfTrue(columnValue int, columnName varchar(10))
  RETURNS varchar(10) 
BEGIN
declare s varchar(10);
IF columnValue = 1 THEN
    set s = concat(columnName , ' ');
else
    set s = ' ';
END IF;
  RETURN s;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then, the solution will be:

```
select id, rtrim(concat(returnNameIfTrue(colA, 'colA'), 
    returnNameIfTrue(colB, 'colB'), 
    returnNameIfTrue(colC, 'colC'), 
    returnNameIfTrue(colD, 'colD'))) as type
from tableName
```

Or, if you also want to get rid of additional space:

```
select id, replace(replace(replace(rtrim(concat(returnNameIfTrue(colA, 'colA'), 
    returnNameIfTrue(colB, 'colB'), 
    returnNameIfTrue(colC, 'colC'), 
    returnNameIfTrue(colD, 'colD'))), '  ', ' '), '  ', ' '), '  ', ' ') as type
from tableName
```

Comment: How would this handle the commas in the list?

Comment: Well, if they are necessary to be removed, then they may be removed using another function; select deleteAdditionalCommas(returnNameIfTrue(colA, 'colA')) ...

Answer (score 0):

Easily achievable using Unpivot operator:

```
;WITH unpivoted AS
(
    SELECT Id, Val, Col
    FROM (SELECT ID, ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD FROM @Data) AS Up
    UNPIVOT (Val FOR Col IN (ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD)) AS Upv
)
SELECT Id, STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Col FROM unpivoted WHERE Id = up.Id AND Val = 'T' FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') AS [Type]
FROM unpivoted up
GROUP BY Id
```